# How to configure WAL archiving for a cluster that *only* hosts dev or test databases?

Tags: postgresql

I've got a dev and test database for a project, i.e. databases that I use to either run my project or run tests, locally. They're both in the same cluster ('instance' – I come from Redmond).

Note that my local cluster is different than the cluster that hosts the production database.

How should I configure those databases with respect to archiving the WAL files?

I'd like to be able to 'build' or 'rebuild' either of those databases by restoring from a base backup and running seed data scripts.

But how should I configure the databases or the cluster for archiving WAL files? I understand that I need them if I want to recover the database. I think that's unlikely (as I didn't even know about 'WAL' or their files, or that, presumably they're shared by all of the databases in the same cluster, which seems weird and scary coming from Microsoft SQL Server.)

In the event that I rebuild one of the databases, I should delete the WAL files since the base backup – how can I do that?

But I also don't want to have to worry about the size of the WAL files growing indefinitely. I don't want to be forced to rebuild just to save space. What can I do to prevent this?

My local cluster *only* contains a single dev and test database for my project, i.e. losing data from one of these databases is (or should be) no big deal. Even having to recreate the cluster itself, and the two databases, is fine and not an issue if it's even just *easier* than otherwise to restore the two databases to a 'working' condition for local development and testing.

In other words, I don't care about the data in either database. I will ensure – separate from WAL archiving – that I can restore either database to a state sufficient for my needs.

Also, I'd like to document (e.g. in code) how to configure my local cluster and the two databases so that other developers for the same project can use the same setup for their *local* clusters. These clusters are all distinct from the cluster that hosts the production database.

Comment: Don't try to develop your own solution. Use one of the various ready-made backup solutions like [barman](https://www.pgbarman.org), [pg_backrest](https://pgbackrest.org/) or [pg_probackup](https://github.com/postgrespro/pg_probackup)

Comment: Regarding your "shared by all databases is weird" - it's not weird at all. Each DBMS works differently and a "database" in SQL Server is a completely different concept than a "database" in Postgres (and then again both are completely different to a "database" in Oracle). The best thing you can do is forget everything you learned about the basic architectural concepts. You need to migrate your mindset too ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You're not joking! It is hard to discuss, or even search for info, because of the terminological differences.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to manage your WAL files manually, it's generally recommended that you let a third-party app take care of that for you.  There are several options, but [`pg_backrest`](https://pgbackrest.org/) is the most popular of the open-source offerings out there.

Comment: `pg_backrest` looks great. I'm thinking of creating a base backup of the two databases after seeding them with fixed dev/test data. I would use that backup to restore the databases to their 'initialized' states as needed. Perhaps one way to minimize the disk space used by WAL archive files is to regularly create a second new base backup, e.g. a daily base backup, (and overwrite the previous 'second' backup file). That way I, and other developers, could restore that base backup, and any WAL archives too, if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Each database instance writes its WAL stream, chopped in segments of 16MB.

Every other relational database does the same thing, even Microsoft SQL Server (the differences are in the name and organization of these files).

The WAL contains the physical information required to replay transactions. Imagine it as information like: "in file x, block 2734, change 24 bytes at offset 543 as follows: ..."

With a base backup and this information you can restore any given point in time in the life of the database **since the end of the base backup**.

Each PostgreSQL cluster writes its own "WAL stream". The files are named with long weird hexadecimal numbers that never repeat, so there is no danger that a later WAL segment of a cluster can conflict with an earlier WAL segment of the same cluster.

You have to make sure that WAL is archived to a different machine, otherwise the exercise is pretty useless. If you have several clusters on the same machine, make sure that you archive them to different directories (or locations in general), because the names of the WAL segments of different clusters **will** collide.

About retention: You want to keep around your backups for some time. Once you get rid of a base backup, you can also get rid of all WAL segments from **before** that base backup. There is the `pg_archivecleanup` executable that can help you get rid of all archived WAL segments older than a given base backup.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server writes separate WAL streams ('transaction log files') for each database – I was surprised that PostgreSQL only does so for an entire cluster ('SQL Server instance' in MSSQL).

Comment: In my scenario, the relevant cluster is purely for local development and testing, i.e. it runs on my laptop. An entirely separate cluster hosts the production database and is running elsewhere (i.e. a different computer). I *would* like to use base backups – see [this comment of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443404/how-to-configure-wal-archiving-for-dev-or-test-databases/58445103#comment103246001_58444582), on another answer to this question, which describes how I'm thinking of using them. But I'm mainly interested in minimizing the disk space used by WAL archive files.

Comment: To just have backups without PITR, use either `pg_dump` (simple, space efficient) or `pg_basebackup` with `-X stream`. Then you can set `archive_mode = off` and not archive WAL at all.

Comment: What should I do about the WAL archive files themselves? Just periodically delete them? Or is there a better/safer command to do the same thing?

Comment: If you disable archiving, there will be no archives and nothing to delete.

Comment: How can I disable archiving?

Comment: Like I said, set `archive_mode = off` in `postgresql.conf` and restart.

Comment: Great; thanks! I thought that was an option for `pg_dump` or `pg_basebackup`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to be able to 'build' or 'rebuild' either of those databases by restoring from a base backup and running seed data scripts.

Where is the basebackup coming from?  If you are restoring the PROD base backup and running the seed scripts over it, then you don't need WAL archiving at all on test/dev.  But then what you get will be a clone of PROD, which means it will not have different databases for test and for dev in the same instance, since (presumably) PROD doesn't have that.

If the base backup is coming from someplace else, you will have to describe what it is.  That will dictate your WAL needs.

Trying to run one instance with both test and dev on it seems like a false economy to me.  Just run two instances.

Setting `archive_mode=off` will entirely disable a wal archive.  There will still be "live" WAL files in the pg_wal or pg_xlog directory, but these get removed/recycled automatically after each checkpoint--you should not need to manage these, other than by controlling how often checkpoints take place (and making sure you don't have any replication slots hanging around).  The WAL archive and the live WAL files are different things.  The live WAL files are mandatory and are needed to automatically recover from something like a power failure.  The WAL archive may be needed to manually recover from a hard-drive crash or the total destruction of your server, and probably isn't needed at all on dev/test.

Comment: Great questions! I edited the question to include some more pertinent details. I'm *not* restoring a production base backup to the relevant cluster. Right now, we have code that creates the database and its schema, e.g. tables, indexes, constraints. We also have code that seeds the database with 'static data' (e.g. postal codes) and test data, e.g. for running the project on a developer's computer. Note also that the production *cluster* is entirely separate from this/these clusters. These clusters *only* host dev/test databases.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a base backup of both the 'initialized' dev/test databases, i.e. after running the code that creates the database, its tables, etc. and seeds it with test data. That would allow quickly restoring the databases to a known 'working' state. I don't *need* WAL archiving at all – we could always recreate these databases or even recreate the cluster entirely – but it doesn't seem possible to *entirely* disable WAL archiving. I'm looking for a way to manage the WAL archive files, i.e. minimize the disk space they use.

Comment: "but it doesn't seem possible to entirely disable WAL archiving."  It is, I think you are confusing archiving with checkpointing.  See my edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've got most of the puzzle – dev/test (only) clusters should be configured to disable (WAL) archiving. As the maximum checkpoint timeout is one hour, the size of the 'live' WAL files doesn't seem likely to be a problem unless I was, e.g. stress-testing the cluster or its databases.